# In particle filter: what is the meaning of $\pi_n(x_n|x_{1:n-1})$?

Tags: filters, kalman-filters, bayesian-estimation, probability, particle-filter

In the survey article of particle filter *A Tutorial on Particle Filtering and Smoothing: Fifteen years later*, the equation (39) are
$$
\begin{aligned}
\pi_{n}\left(x_{n} \mid x_{1: n-1}\right) &=p\left(x_{n} \mid y_{n}, x_{n-1}\right) \\
&=\frac{g\left(y_{n} \mid x_{n}\right) f\left(x_{n} \mid x_{n-1}\right)}{p\left(y_{n} \mid x_{n-1}\right)}
\end{aligned}
$$

I have two questions about this formula.

1. Since we choose $\pi_{n}\left(x_{1: n}\right)=p\left(x_{1: n} \mid y_{1: n}\right)$ for filtering, how to understand $\pi_{n}\left(x_{n} \mid x_{1: n-1}\right) =p\left(x_{n} \mid y_{n}, x_{n-1}\right)$ ?
2. $x_n$ is assumed to be a Markov process, why here $p\left(x_{n} \mid y_{n}, x_{n-1}\right)$ does not equal $p\left(x_{n} \mid x_{n-1}\right)$ but $\frac{g\left(y_{n} \mid x_{n}\right) f\left(x_{n} \mid x_{n-1}\right)}{p\left(y_{n} \mid x_{n-1}\right)}$ ?

Comment: You need to define all these notations especially $f(\cdot)$, $g(\cdot)$ because the paper you are reading is not a classic well-known one and even if it were, nobody on the Internet can remember what the author would mean with their notations without re-reading the paper.

Comment: Now, after skimming the paper, *it seems that* (1) $\pi_{n}\left(x_{n} \mid x_{1: n-1}\right)$ means the distribution $p(\cdot)$ of $x_n$ given $x_{1: n-1}$ (by conventional usage of the conditional probability distribution notations) and $y_n$ (by the definition of $\pi_n(\cdot)$).

Comment: (2) $\lbrace x_n \rbrace_n$ is Markov  does not mean what you asked but simply $p(x_n | x_{1: n-1})=p(x_n | x_{n-1})$. The equality of Eq (39) could be obtained by using the Bayes' theorem (I don't know the definition of f and g).